# Author-year style citations between brackets

Tags: natbib

I use the package [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) together with the bibtex style `abbrvnat`. I obtain citations like [Gaucher, 2010a].  If I put directly the bbl file produced by the compilation in the LaTeX file, I obtain citations like (Gaucher, 2010a). Why are the brackets replaced by parentheses ? I absolutely need brackets and I must absolutely put the bbl file in the latex file. The journal does not want a separated bibtex file.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question an hour ago, found the solution and deleted the question afterwards?

Comment: No that was a different question, about natbib too indeed.

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Do you happen to load the `natbib` package with the option `square`? What happens if you load the package with the option `round`?

Comment: @Mico \usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib} is the solution. I did not know the option 'square'. It's the first time I use this bibtex style. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I absolutely need brackets and I must absolutely put the bbl file in the latex file.

In that case, be sure to provide the option `square` when loading `natbib`:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
```